# Frameworks comparation: Lift, Play and Wicket

Tags: scala, wicket, lift, playframework

What are the advantages and dis­advantages of frameworks Lift, Play and Wicket? What characteristics are best or only supported by each?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a framework with scala-support?

Comment: @niels Yes Another feature, besides those cited in the question, is enabling a good separation of the layers of the system. The framework that I liked was the Wicket. If necessary I will make a custom bracket to use it with Scala.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Play**:

Lightweight Java-based framework, with Scala support available as an extra.

very good for rapid prototyping, fast-feedback-loop kind of work.  Embeds the compiler, so you just edit source code in place and pages get immediately updated.  Learning curve is shallow.

**Wicket**:

Stateful Java-based framework, with Scala support available as an extra.

Shallower learning curve into Scala, especially if you already have wicket experience.
Good separation of concerns, POJO-based model.  Arguably one of the best Java web frameworks currently available.

**Lift**:

Stateful native-Scala framework.
Deep Scala integration, so no need to generate bean setter/getter methods or worry about interop between Java/Scala collections.  Fully embraces functional-programming concepts, such as immutability and closures.

Also the steepest learning-curve of the three.  One common piece of advice is therefore to learn the Scala language before getting started with Lift, especially if you come from a Java background.

**Others**:

There are also other Scala-based frameworks available (such as Scalatra and Pinky) for web development, though not as well-known as Lift.  It wouldn't hurt to check these out as well!

For more information, see this question: [What Scala web-frameworks are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488412/what-scala-web-frameworks-are-available)

Comment: Clear as crystal, as always when coming from you @Kevin

Comment: Hey, thanks!  But you do know this'll probably send me on some sort of ego-trip right?

Comment: @eelco: You can tell which one I haven't used then?  I've updated the answer

Comment: I'm guessing that the description for Play was for Play 1.x, since Play 2 (which came along well after this answer was written) really embraces Scala wholeheartedly (while still supporting Java).

Answer (score 12):

There are many threads that compares these web frameworks for Scala. See

[Which is better framework Java/GWT or Scala/Lift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948067/which-is-better-framework-java-gwt-or-scala-lift)

Lift / Wicket here: [Which is better framework Java/GWT or Scala/Lift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948067/which-is-better-framework-java-gwt-or-scala-lift)

[For my next project, a web-app, should use scala+wicket or scala+lift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231998/for-my-next-project-a-web-app-should-use-scalawicket-or-scalalift)

[How do the Scala based frameworks stack up for a complete Scala newbie - Lift, Play, Circumflex, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164071/how-do-the-scala-based-frameworks-stack-up-for-a-complete-scala-newbie-lift-pl)

Comment: You do not have to follow these links. Actually, Kevins answer saiz it all.

Comment: These links were very helpful, especially the first. Thanks

Comment: No, please, *do* follow the links!  My summary was very broad - there's a lot more to learn in the fine print.  **I** certainly upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Talking about the advantages of Lift, one should mention [Seven Things](http://seventhings.liftweb.net) where Lift really excels. In short:

- Lazy Loading
- Parallel page rendering
- Comet and Ajax
- Wiring -- declare interdepencies between page elements
- Designer friendly templates
- Wizard -- multipage input screens with full back-button support
- Security

Just visit the linked page for more details - these features really make Lift unique among competitors.

Answer (score 2):

See also:

https://vaadin.com/ - Stateful Java-based framework for desktop-like applications (GWT based, but server-side, no javascript, no html).

http://click.apache.org/ - stateless Java-based framework for light web applications.

Both have excellent documentation and are easy to learn.